# Javascript call PHP do Recursive write for long text

Tags: php

In order to overcome URI limit of 8K, I have to use a recrusive write by
breaking down long text into chunks and have a recruive write function that calling simple PHP program to write to disk.

A variable chunkAppend set to "" for the first time and then set to append to tell PHP program to append. That work fine until I need a callback from the function to let caller know the write disk job is done!

When the text is small, only one chunk, it work fine, the doneCallback() does as it should be, tell the caller it is done. But when the chunk length is more than one,  it does the job write to disk several chunks and alert(phpWritten); but not doneCallback("done") !

What could be happening in javascript that alter the doneCallback() in the recursive process?

The skelton is as follow:

```
<pre><code>

caller:
var chunkCnt;
var chunk=[];
var chunkAppend="";
var phpWritten="";

// set up chunk[] array and chunkCnt before call
writeChunk(url, 0, function(rtn) { alert(rtn); });

function writeChunk(url, start, doneCallback) {

 var prog="/acwphp/API_Write_TextFile.php?fullname="+ 
 encodeURIComponent(url) + chunkAppend + "&text=" + chunk[start];

  runExternalProg(prog, function(rtn) {
     // php return no of bytes written
     phpWritten = phpWritten + start + "--" + rtn + "\n";
     ++start;
     chunkAppend = "&append=yes";

     if (start >= chunk.length) { alert(phpWritten); 
            doneCallback(start+"..done.."); }
     else { writeChunk(url, start, function(rtn) {}); }
     });    
}
</code></pre>
```

Comment: There is no general "URI limit of 8K". Why do you claim that? There might be limitations in specific components, software components, sure. But that actually only indicates that you are miss using a technology for something it was to designed for.

Comment: It appears you are trying to submit bigger data sets as http get arguments. Is there a specific reason why you do not use http post requests which are much better suited for that? There is a reason why both verbs exist...

Comment: I use Hostgator service and it's Apache server has a 8K limit. The error message  said URI too long if the text length longer than 8K.  I am not using HTML form so no get/post issue involved and not sure how to use it.

Comment: http get or post requests have nothing to do with whether you have a html form or not. The http protocol is a _transport_ protocol, it is independent from the _content_. Any http client is capable of doing post requests.

Comment: Sorry I did not get it. In Javascript, I simply construct a PHP call with filename=..fullpath name...&txt=...long string...,  so where do I tell it is a post or a get? The PHP is very simply use _REQUEST to get data and write to file., only a dozen of lines!

Comment: You will easily find examples for doing http post requests by means of javascript. And by the way: you do _not_ construct a "PHP call" in javascript. You make a http to some URL you build. If that request is processed by a PHP script depends on other things, namely your setup.

Comment: Has tried to test on function 'runExternalProg' which indeed has a GET but I tried set to to POST, the result still the same. The 8K limit according to some web advice can only be altered by Apache administrator. So any suggestion for save  big data to file from javascrript?

Comment: You did not understand the difference between a GET and a POST request. And quite obvious you also did not try to find out. In a POST request you do NOT specify the payload as part of the URL (otherwise where would be the difference to a GET request?) but in the request _body_. That can be as big as you want it to.